# Is there a subarray that sums to a target?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Popular interview question:

Given an array of positive integers and a target integer, find if there is a consecutive subarray that sums to the target.

E.g.

Array = `[1,3,6,7,8,10]`
Target = `16`
The subarray that sums to 16 is `[3,6,7]`, so it returns true.

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Comment: Wait a minute...what language do you want to use?

Comment: Any language is fine. It's more about the logic. @TimBiegeleisen, your answer makes sense and it seems to work. In terms of complexity, this seems to be O(N^2). Is there any way this can be made more efficient?

Comment: I didn't realize you answered your own question :-)  You could try sorting the array in `O(NlgN)` time, but I don't see any way which a sorted array would help.

Comment: A linear-time algorithm should do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one goes linear time (C++ code).

```
bool Test(const int* arr, int size, int target) {
  if (target < 0) return false;
  int acc = 0;
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (acc != target) {
    if (acc < target) {
      if (j == size) break;
      acc += arr[j++];
    }
    else {
      acc -= arr[i++];
    }
  }
  return acc == target;
}
```

Note that the pre-check for a negative target value is necessary to guarantee the loop invariant that `i <= j`. Specifically, when `i == j`, `acc` will be `0`, and a positive target guarantees that the branch under `if (acc < target)` is hit.

Comment: @TonyD I don't think so. It assumes positive integers in the array as described in the question.

Comment: it looks like it handles target=0 wrongly.... You say "positive target" but check for non-negative.....

Comment: @gen-y-s When `target` is `0`, the `while` loop is not entered at all and `acc == target` (which is `true`) is returned. So, a target value of `0` always results in `true` being returned. This should be correct when we treat the sum of an empty sub-array to be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote and fully tested. Two methods, hasConsec (where most of the logic is) and sumArr (helper method that sums values in an array). hasConsec and uses 2 indexes, first and last, to create subarrays. The helper method is used to sum the subarray created and then hasConsec checks if it matches the target, if it's greater than the target, or if it's less than the target. If it matches, it returns true; if the sum is less than the target, the last index is incremented; if it's greater than the target, then first index is incremented. Repeat until the first index is equal to the length of the array. If that happens, there's no subarray that sums to the target. Return false;

```java
public static boolean hasConsec(int arr[], int target) {
    int first = 0, last = 0;

    while (last <  arr.length) {
        int sub[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, first, last);
        int subSum = sumArr(sub);
        if (subSum == target) 
             return true;
        else if (subSum < target)
             last++;
        else {
            if (++first < last)
                last = first;
         }
     }
    return false;
}

public static int sumArr(int arr[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        sum += arr[i];
     return sum;
 }
```